# Used object tag in Angular but not found camera

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bigbluebutton

I am trying to display Angular website inside another website using object tag.I used bigbluebutton in object tag.I need to use camera on website in the object tag but camera not found.Bigbluebuttom when open different tab, working camera.

Here is my code

```js
openVirtual(url) {
    //url = https://xxxx.bigbluebutton.com/html5client/
    
    this.urlVirtual = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url); 
    this.isBigBlueButtom = true;

}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="isBigBlueButtom" id="box">
  <object type="text/html" [attr.data]="urlVirtual">
  </object>
</div
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe it is this spelling error: *ngIf="isBigBlueButtom"

Comment: I don't think it's related to it. Bigbluebutton is working. Problem is not found camera.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
Here is my code

```js
<div *ngIf="isBigBlueButtom" id="box">
  <iframe type="text/html" [src]="urlVirtual" allow="camera; microphone">
  </iframe>
</div
```